# Remove rows of unidentified individuals if another individual that has been identified further, was recorded at the same time, in r

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements, dataset

I have a dataset with insect observation data from which I would like to remove some rows based on what else was observed during the same occasion, treatment and on the same plant species.

For example, I would like to remove an "Unidentified Hymenoptera" if during the same year, round, site, treatment and plant species another solitary bee is observed.

Hence, in the example picture below, of all that was observed on "Site1" in year "2021",during round "3", in treatment "P" and on "plant2", all "Unidentified Hymenoptera" should be removed.

However, from Site2, in 2021, during round 3, in treatment P, on plant1, Unidentified Hymenoptera should be kept, since there is no other Solitary bee observed during the occasion. The end goal is to calculate the number of species per treatment, occasion and plant (and that I know how to do). In my full dataset there are also for example unidentified species like "Chelostoma spp." that should only be removed if there are other "Chelostoma" (in the "genus" column) present at the same treatment, occasion and on the same plant species.

[image]
[image]

Here is a small sample of my dataset:

```
df<- structure(list(SiteID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), levels = c("Site1", "Site2"), class = "factor"), Year = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "2021", class = "factor"), 
    Round = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), levels = c("2", "3"), class = "factor"), Treatment = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("P", "PX"
    ), class = "factor"), Plant_species = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("plant1", "plant2", 
    "plant3"), class = "factor"), family = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L), levels = c("Andrenidae", 
    "Halictidae", "Megachilidae", "Melittidae", "Unidentified Hymenoptera"
    ), class = "factor"), genus = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
    2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L), levels = c("Andrena", "Chelostoma", 
    "Lasioglossum", "Melitta", "Unidentified Hymenoptera"), class = "factor"), 
    species = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
    4L), levels = c("Andrena spp.", "Chelostoma campanularum", 
    "Lasioglossum quadrinotatum", "Melitta haemorrhoidalis", 
    "Unidentified Hymenoptera"), class = "factor"), Insect = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "Solitary bee", class = "factor")), row.names = c(1570L, 
1574L, 1576L, 1579L, 1583L, 1587L, 1598L, 1624L, 2860L, 2875L, 
2894L, 2900L, 2906L, 2907L, 2925L, 2932L, 2937L, 2952L, 2953L, 
2960L, 2966L, 2967L, 2968L, 2987L, 2988L), class = "data.frame")
```

Can someone guide me in how to accomplish this? My programming skills are not good at all, so I don't know were to begin.

I have not tried anything yet, as I don't know were to start. I was thinking that maybe an ifelse statement could be the way to go, but I don't know how I would remove rows with that. Or maybe with the help of group_by(), filter() and distinct() in dplyr... All help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is your expected output? The row you mention (Site2, in 2021, during round 3, in treatment P, on plant1, Unidentified Hymenoptera) there are two observations with "Solitary bee".

Comment: Yes, that is the only "species" observed during that occasion, two individuals. So both of those rows with "Unidentified..." should stay. When I later on calculate the number of species per plant species, treatment and occasion there, it will be counted as 1 species. In the upper picture there is one individual of the species Melitta haemorrhoidalis, and two individuals of the species Chelostoma campunularum. I cannot know if the Unidentified Hymenoptera belong to any of those two species. Therefore the unidentified needs to be removed so that the species count there, later on is 2 and not 3.

Comment: Each row is one individual. I could have aggregated the data before (and in my real data I do), but that doesn't change the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're wanting something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

unIDd_chelostoma <- c("Chelostoma spp.")

df |>
  group_by(SiteID, Year, Round, Treatment, Plant_species) |>
  filter(!(sum(Insect == "Solitary bee") > 1 & species == "Unidentified Hymenoptera" & any(species != "Unidentified Hymenoptera")),
            !(sum(genus == "Chelostoma") > 1 & species %in% unIDed_chelostoma & any(species != "Chelostoma spp."))) |>
  ungroup()
```

Comment: So this works on my little sample data. I Tried it on another sample data with syrphids, like this: test2<-df2 |>
  group_by(SiteID, Year, Round, Treatment, Plant_species) |>
  filter(!(sum(Insect == "Syrphids") > 1 & species == "Unidentified Syrphidae" & any(species != "Unidentified Syrphidae")),
         !(sum(family == "Syrphidae") > 1 & species %in% unIDd_Syrph & any(species != "Unidentified Syrphidae"))) |>
  ungroup()
removedsyrphs<-anti_join(df2,test2)

Comment: ..and yes? did you get the correct result?

Comment: However, it does not work on my full dataset where I have a lot more columns, then it just removed way more Unidentified Syrphids than it should, and also rows with NA. Do I need to specify all my columns for it to work. And where and how would I put in the "don't touch my NAs"?